# price engine configuration

Tags: price

My question is about forming market data which is received from the LPs.
Some tools work with these parameters: min spread, max spread, bid spread, ask spread.
If current spread < min spread or current spread > max spread then it changes the bid/ask values. Bid and Ask spread parameters work similar also.
Is there another way to form the market data?